# Interchanging/Swapping values between mysql fields

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

So, after creating the field, the code and what else was needed to retrieve news order as mentioned here: [Planning news ordering system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515027/planning-news-ordering-system/10515231)

I have encountered another dilemma:

- Having row **`X`** with order value **`17`** and row **`Y`** with order value **`19`**, which is the best way to interchange their values for mysql with php code?

### UPDATE

My meaning of interchange is: change a value with another.

What I am trying to achieve is similar as joomla does the sorting for its data. http://awesomescreenshot.com/01658u06e

`sn_news` table:

```
....   id     order   title  
       ====   =====   =======
       1231   1       ASDAASD
       1331   2       ASDXXSD
       1221   3       ASDBBSD
       1731   4       ASDYYSD
       1531   5       ASDCCSD
```

I want to swap id `1221`'s order `3` with the order `5` from id `1531` so it would become:

```
....   id     order   title  
       ====   =====   =======
       1231   1       ASDAASD
       1331   2       ASDXXSD
 -->   1221   5       ASDBBSD
       1731   4       ASDYYSD
 -->   1531   3       ASDCCSD
```

Comment: What do you mean by interchanging values? Do you want to rename these two columns?

Comment: Altering table and interchanging column name would be more beneficial and if you still want to change values then you will need one more column.If you really want then i can tell you

Comment: ok, question updated with more info.... meanwhile I'm reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql and http://www.microshell.com/database/sql/swap-values-in-2-rows-sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the best i can understand

```
Update table_name set order=5 where id=1221;
Update table_name set order=3 where id=1531;
```

Comment: That's what I thought of too, at first, but I'm not so sure it is a good way of doin it